# Who makes tools auto documenting/analysing legacy code and which is better?

Tags: refactoring, reverse-engineering, documentation-generation, legacy-code

Who else makes tools like Scitools Understand C++ and which is better?

Looking for the most complete auto documentation tools for Ada, C, C++ and Fortran.  For analysis of tool migration effort, to aid to in pruning dead code and identifying essential functionality.

Pete

Answer (score 1):

Ctags + cscope + kscope ui
Cxref
Doxygen